# Highcharts/Highstock running laps

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on a graph for runners, that chart must be scrollable like in Highstock. How can I show the laps with scroll function?

```
chart = Highcharts.stockChart({
         chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
           type: "line"
         },
         credits:{
           enabled: false
         },
       series: data
     });
```

Edit:

I have this
[image]
I wanne make a horizontal scroll like this
[image]
If I use Highcharts I can not make a scroll. If I use Highstock there are dates instead of laps. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Jur Dekker, Could you provide us with more detailed description of the problem? Also, in your case some visualisation in the picture would be very useful.

Comment: @ppotaczek I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highstock code and `chart` constructor, which will allow you use Highstock features in standard chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xf5ka8un/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar